# JNLP application fails with error about missing jniwrap64.dll

Tags: java, internet-explorer, jnlp

I have a JNLP application which fails with the following error:

> Cannot find JNIWrapper native library (jniwrap64.dll) in java.library.path: ....

I have Java 8 64bit installed and using IE11.

Any help on how to fix it will be appreciated.

Just to clarify: I did not write the application and only trying to run it.

Answer (score 2):

You need 32bit java version to launch the JNLP application and not 64bit java
please run below command to check what version of java you are running

```
C:\RIM\SINGTEL\950_0\inproc>java -d64 -version
java version "1.8.0_40"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_40-b26)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.40-b25, mixed mode)
```

Java HotSpot(TM) ***64-Bit Server*** VM (build 25.40-b25, mixed mode)